# Finding Data in Rows with some Duplicate Row Names in R

Tags: r

I have a set of data that comes to us that I need specific rows from.

But the data comes in as:

```
Row A
Row 1
Row 2
Row 3
Row 4
Row 5
Row 6

Row B
Row 1
Row 2
Row 3
Row 4
Row 5
Row 6

Row C
Row 1
Row 2
Row 3
Row 4
Row 5
Row 6
```

Where Rows 1-6 have repeated row names, but Rows A, B, C are different. I need it to pull the specific rows where row = Row A Name and Row 1 Name, Row B Name and Row 1 Name. However, these rows might change if more facilities are added so I can't do a "go down one row" function. It has to say "Look for Row A then find Row 1 but don't go past Row B and find Row 1 again."

Any thoughts?

Comment: are those rownames? R does not allow duplicated rownames. Please use `dput` to make your example reproducible

Comment: Is there an empty line above Row A, above Row B, above Row C but not above Rows1, 2, 3, ...? You could split the data into a list of lists. list[[1]] contains als Row A data and list[[2]] contains all Row B data and so on. That being said, make your example reproducible for further advice.